# Using query parameters with multiple values in Scala Dispatch 0.9.5

Tags: scala, scala-dispatch

I'm using the excellent [Dispatch](http://dispatch.databinder.net/) library to make HTTP requests like so:

```
Http(url("http://foo.bar/baz").GET <<? Map("param1" -> "value1") OK as.String)
```

However, I'm talking to a REST service that expects `param1` to be a list of values. How can I accomplish this in Dispatch?

I see in the source code that `<<?` takes a `Traversable[(String,String)]`, so maybe it is as easy as passing a `Traversable` that allows keys to appear multiple times. Is there such a beast? I've been poking through the Scala API docs, but I can't find one that would seem to fit the bill.

Failing that, is there a way to hook into the request builder? I see that Dispatch uses a `com.ning.http.client.RequestBuilder`, on which I could call `addQueryParameter()` myself.

Answer (score 4):

Well, after a bit more slogging through the Scala API docs, I had an epiphany! `List` itself mixes in `Traversable`, so a list of something for which `apply(String, String)` will do the trick. Tuples to the rescue:

```
Http(url("http://foo.bar/baz").GET <<? List(("param1" -> "value1"), ("param1" -> "value2")) OK as.String)
```

Comment: What did you import for this example to work? I get `cannot resolve method "Http.apply"`.